# Installing imagetk module

Tags: python

I have installed pillow but getting the error as imagetk is not recognised in the version

Error that image and imagetk is not recognised in the version
I have uninstalled and installed pillow several time but the same error comes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.